# Adding Email Attachments From Local Storage

Tags: laravel, storage, lumen

I am using laravel/lumen. I am able to save files using `Storage::disk("local")->put();` in my storage directory.  However now I want to attach a few of those files to an email and send, this is done with a job the error I get is

> lumen.ERROR: exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to
>   open file for reading

Now I read something about symbolic linking which I tried but that simply did not change the result, I was still unable to attach files i n my storage folder to my emails.

This is my directory structure:

**/home/xxxxxx/:**

**-example.app**

--storage

---app

----public

**-public_html**

--example.app

---storage

Attaching the file like this:

```
foreach ($params["attachments"] as $attachment) {
    $mail->attach($attachment["file"], [
        'as' => $attachment["name"],
        'mime' => $attachment["mime"]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: How are you attaching the file?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: What are `$params["attachments"]`? Are they from a form?

Comment: It's basically an array of file names and no they're not from a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently swift mailer fails when you pass a full url instead of the real path to the file.  Didn't know this, don't know if it's a bug or it was done by design.

Answer (score 2):

You've already realized that `attach()` method expects the full path to the file. However, others may find useful know how to achieve that. So, in case you're using the default settings for **local** store, you may be able to get the full path by calling the `storage_path()` helper. This way:

```
/*
 * This will return the full path to the file:
 *
 * /path/to/laravel/storage/app/attachment/path
 */
storage_path('app/' . $attachment['file']);
```